# Adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I can't figure out why I can't add items to the ArrayList. I have tried a couple different ways of adding items and they don't work.

```
class Problem {
public ArrayList<String> problems = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

private String question1 = "What is 2+2?";
private String question2 = "What is the square root of 25";
private String question3 = "What is the next number in the sequence? {2, 4, 6}";
private String question4 = "What is 8*8?";



String[] temp1 = {question1, question2, question3, question4};


for (String s : temp1)
    problems.add(s);

}
```

I have also tried

```
problems.add(question1);
problems.add(question2);
problems.add(question3);
problems.add(question4);
```

This does not work either.

Compiler says that identifier is expected.

Comment: Adding the items needs to be in a method or in an initializer. Why do you put them in an array then add to the list? Why not just add them to the list?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `import java.util.ArrayList;` to the top of your file.

You also need a `main` method to run, with a signature like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Also, you should make the string constants `final` (and/or `static`) if you don't plan on changing them.

Finally, `temp1` is the default ("friend") visibility.

I'm assuming this is a code snippet rather than what you actually ran.

Comment: Yes its just a small piece of a larger program. Adding the main() method seems to have solved my problem.  Thank you.  Dumb mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Problem {

public static ArrayList<String> problems = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

private static String question1 = "What is 2+2?";
private static String question2 = "What is the square root of 25";
private static String question3 = "What is the next number in the sequence? {2, 4, 6}"; 
private static String question4 = "What is 8*8?";

public static void main(String [] args) {

String[] temp1 = {question1, question2, question3, question4};


for (String s : temp1)
    problems.add(s);

System.out.println(""+problems);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're missing a method declaration.

Try putting your code inside of a Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] temp1 = {question1, question2, question3, question4};


  for (String s : temp1)
      problems.add(s);

  }
}
```